# ASP textbox template controlled from drop down

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, drop-down-menu

I'm trying to get a drop down to insert a template into a text box, ideally not with a DB just hard code through an event or similar, unless I can keep styling through the database (font colours etc).

The text box and drop down are within an `updatepanel` in a `listview`. I want to add more functionality so that they don't have to manually type text into the text box, when they choose an option from the drop down list it will automatically populate the text box with the relevant choice.

I am having trouble with how to associate the `onClick` functionality on the drop down with the text box.

Any guides or help would be appreciated.

My asp code:

```
<asp:panel runat="server" ID="Panel1">
 <table id="insert" runat="server">
    <tr style="">
        <td>
            <asp:Button ID="InsertButton" runat="server" CommandName="Insert" Text="Insert" />
            <asp:Button ID="CancelButton" runat="server" CommandName="Cancel" Text="Clear" />
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr >
        <td>
            <asp:TextBox ID="TxtBx" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Details")%>' Width="100%" TextMode="MultiLine" Rows="20" />
        </td>
        <td>
            <asp:DropDownList ID="DDL" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True">
                <asp:ListItem>Select</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem> Template One </asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem> Template Two </asp:ListItem>
            </asp:DropDownList>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

The VB.NET code behind:

```
    Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    If DDL.Text <> "Select" Then
        TxtBx.Text = DDL.Text
    End If
End Sub

    Protected Sub DDL_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles DDL.SelectedIndexChanged
    TxtBx.Text = DDL.Text
End Sub
```

UPDATE:

I've gotten the ddl to paste into the text box using VB, is  it possible to grab a .txt file with a template (just text inside) and paste this into the text box. So, DDL Item template 1 link to textfile1.txt, if template one is chose, the corresponding text file's text will be pasted in?

UPDATE 2:

I have got the event handler to paste into the text box when the ddl is clicked, however I don't know how to reference one item from the drop down to reference a specific file so it uploads the correct file on item selection.

Handler code:

```
    Protected Sub DDL_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles DDL.SelectedIndexChanged
    'TxtBx.Text = DDL.Text
    TxtBx.Text = My.Computer.FileSystem.ReadAllText("E:\Users\me\DummyTemplate.txt")
End Sub
```

Comment: Please explain your question more clearly, what do you want to do that is not done in this code? do you want to change background color of `TextBox` on `OnSelectedIndexChanged` for instance?

Comment: What I'm trying to achieve: templates associated with listitems that when selected will populate the textbox with said template.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use values within the ASP so that the code behind can associate it with this and choose template files, however I don't know if this will give the layout you require.

Tried and tested with Chrome using VS2013

ASP:

```
        <asp:DropDownList ID="DDL" runat="server" Width="80px" AutoPostBack="true" >
            <asp:ListItem>Select</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem Value="1">Option 1</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem Value="2">Option 2</asp:ListItem>
        </asp:DropDownList>
```

Code behind VB:

```
        Protected Sub DDL_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles DDL.SelectedIndexChanged
    If DDL.SelectedValue = 1 Then
        TxtBx.Text = My.Computer.FileSystem.ReadAllText("E:\Users\ben\DummyTemplate.txt")
    ElseIf DDL.SelectedValue = 2 Then
        TxtBx.Text = My.Computer.FileSystem.ReadAllText("E:\Users\ben\DifferentTemplate.txt")
    End If
```